# Center logo within nav bar bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to center my logo within my navbar, I am using Bootstrap.

When I inspect the element and hover over my a tag that holds the logo I can see a box that is centered horizontally and vertically. However, my logo sits below it for some reason.

Here is a link to the test site.

http://test.envera.co.uk/

And below is my header code.

```
<div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="fa fa-bars"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                            <img id="logo-header" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();  ?>/img/Envera_Telecom_Logo_Final.png" alt="Logo">
                        </a>
                    </div>
```

Comment: add max-height:100% to `#logo-header` and make the padding of its container 0 `navbar-brand`

Comment: This ^^^ your logo is not below it, but in it, but it's just too big

Comment: You can add `top: 0; padding: 0; height: auto;` to `.navbar-brand`

Answer (score 1):

Update the logo css to

```
#logo-header {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

and from `.navbar-brand` remove padding

Comment: there is already height with navbar ... simply remove the padding

Answer (score 1):

Remove the class `navbar-brand` from your anchor tag. That will fix the issue.

```
<a href="index.html">
    <img id="logo-header" src="http://test.envera.co.uk/wp-content/themes/html5blank-stable/img/Envera_Telecom_Logo_Final.png" alt="Logo">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the css of

> .header-v3 .navbar-brand

located in header.css to

```
.header-v3 .navbar-brand {
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
    position: relative;
}
```